# PHP, mySQL, and xampp login form problems

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I'm creating a Log-in Form for my employees. I think there's a port problem with my local host port for mySQL on xampp but I don't know. Aren't Apache and mySQL supposed to be run from the same port? but anyway...

On xampp, my apache port is 8080 so "localhost:8080". My mySQL port is 3306 so I used "localhost:3306" for my "$host" variable in my php. Now, "login.php" is the "form action" I used in my html which is also the name of the document, so my php and my html are all on the same page - no separate documents; just to clear that up.

The problem: When I click the equivalent of "submit", none of my "echoed" or "error" code goes through. Basically, the page stays the same. Nothing happens. If I screw up the password on purpose, none of my errors come through. I stay on the same page, unable to see if ANYTHING worked. There's nothing to show me if what I did worked or not.

My *phpMyAdmin* database name is "accounts" and the table is named "users".

My php is located [here](http://main.xfiddle.com/f4d2d42e/sqlphpProblems.txt)

My html is located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/baL7mfpf/)

**Again:**

***PHP***

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $host = "localhost:3306";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "password";
    $db = "accounts";

    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db);

    if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
        $username = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User='".$user."' AND Pass='".$pass."' LIMIT 1";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
            echo "You have successfully logged in.";
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Invalid login information. Please return to the previous page.";
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

***HTML***

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<p>User</p><input type="text" name="user" size="30" />
<p>Pass</p><input type="password" name="pass" size="30" />
</br><p><submit><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" /></submit></p>
</form>
```

Please help. I have to get this up and running for an event I have in a week and a half and I still have a LOT of work to do because this has taken me too long.

Thank You,
*Dan*

Comment: What is `ession_start()`?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen The last brace is for `if (isset($_POST['user']))` and OP might have made a typo and meant to do `session_start();` - Many a time, it's a bad copy/paste. Edit: You've edited your comment in regards to my first part.

Comment: Yes, sorry, bad copy/paste.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Also, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: You're using the wrong variables in `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User='".$user."' AND Pass='".$pass."' LIMIT 1";` look at these `$username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];` error reporting would have thrown an Undefined variable notice.

Comment: I'm getting "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Project.Orange\staff\login.php on line 9
Invalid login information. Please return to the previous page."

Comment: I do not know which version of php I'm using. I'm new to php. is there any way to tell?

Comment: Create a new file with `<?php phpinfo();` it will tell you. I also posted an answer below explaining a few things about the use of the wrong variables with links to other MySQL APIs.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User='".$user."' AND Pass='".$pass."' LIMIT 1"; What do you mean by the wrong variables? How should that line of code be structured then?

Comment: Reload my answer below, I've made a `mysqli_` version near the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong variables in

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User='".$user."' AND Pass='".$pass."' LIMIT 1";
```

Look at these, those are the variables you should be using.

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];`
```

Error reporting would have thrown an Undefined variable notice.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Plus this:

```
<submit><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" /></submit>
```

`<submit></submit>` are invalid tags; remove them.

---

I would also like to note that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**Edit:**

As per your comment about deprecation, it's time for you to move to `mysqli_` or PDO.

---

Here is a `mysqli_` basic version and variables fix:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "localhost:3306";
$user = "root";
$pass = "password";
$db = "accounts";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE User='".$username."' AND Pass='".$password."' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    echo "You have successfully logged in.";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Invalid login information. Please return to the previous page.";
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

---

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly! I will learn mySQLi. Thanks again. You saved me a bunch of time!